# How to visit selected link from drop-down list on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select id="atheist">
    <option value="http://google.com"></option>
    <option value="http://yahoo.com"></option
</select>

var select = document.getElementById("select");
select.addEventListener("change",function() { 
    var win = window.open(this.value, "_blank");
    win.focus();
},false);
```

So, i'm trying to visit/go to selected link from drop-down list on a click of a button. Could you help?
If you're ignorant and flying high just pass by this question, don't bother to post a comment.

Comment: Thanks for taking my code and making a duplicate question. -1